# Does Kubernetes consider the current memory usage when scheduling pods

Tags: memory-management, kubernetes

The Kubernetes docs on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/ state:

> The scheduler ensures that, for each resource type, the sum of the resource requests of the scheduled Containers is less than the capacity of the node.

Does Kubernetes consider the current state of the node when calculating capacity? To highlight what I mean, here is a concrete example:

Assuming I have a node with 10Gi of RAM, running 10 Pods each with 500Mi of resource requests, and no limits. Let's say they are "bursting", and each Pod is actually using 1Gi of RAM. In this case, the node is fully utilized (`10 x 1Gi = 10Gi`), but the resources requests are only `10 x 500Mi = 5Gi`. Would Kubernetes consider scheduling another pod on this node because only 50% of the memory capacity on the node has been `requested`, or would it use the fact that 100% of the memory is currently being utilized, and the node is at full capacity?

Answer (score 15):

By default kubernetes will use cgroups to manage and monitor the  "allocatable" memory on a node for pods. It is possible to configure `kubelet` to entirely rely on the static *reservations* and pod *requests* from your deployments though so the method depends on your cluster deployment.

In either case, a node itself will track "memory pressure", which monitors the existing overall memory usage of a node. If a node is under memory pressure then no new pods will be scheduled and existing pods will be evicted.

It's best to set sensible memory *requests* and *limits* for all workloads to help the scheduler as much as possible. 
If a kubernetes deployment does not configure cgroup memory monitoring, setting *requests* is a requirement for *all* workloads.
If the deployment is using cgroup memory monitoring, at least setting *requests* give the scheduler extra detail as to whether the pods to be scheduled should fit on a node.

### Capacity and Allocatable Resources

The [Kubernetes Reserve Compute Resources docco](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/) has a good overview of how memory is viewed on a node.

```
      Node Capacity
---------------------------
|     kube-reserved       |
|-------------------------|
|     system-reserved     |
|-------------------------|
|    eviction-threshold   |
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|      allocatable        |
|   (available for pods)  |
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------
```

The default scheduler checks a node isn't under memory pressure, then looks at the *allocatable* memory available on a node and whether the new pods *requests* will fit in it.

The *allocatable* memory available is the `total-available-memory - kube-reserved - system-reserved - eviction-threshold - scheduled-pods`.

#### Scheduled Pods

The value for `scheduled-pods` can be calculated via a dynamic cgroup, or statically via the pods *resource requests*.

The kubelet `--cgroups-per-qos` option which defaults to `true` enables cgroup tracking of scheduled pods. The pods kubernetes runs will be in

If `--cgroups-per-qos=false` then the *allocatable* memory will only be reduced by the *resource requests* that scheduled on a node.

#### Eviction Threshold

The `eviction-threshold` is the level of free memory when Kubernetes starts evicting pods. This defaults to 100MB but can be set via the kubelet command line. This setting is teid to both the *allocatable* value for a node and also the memory pressure state of a node in the next section.

#### System Reserved

kubelets `system-reserved` value can be configured as a static value (`--system-reserved=`) or monitored dynamically via cgroup (`--system-reserved-cgroup=`).
This is for any system daemons running outside of kubernetes (`sshd`, `systemd` etc). If you configure a cgroup, the processes all need to be placed in that cgroup.

#### Kube Reserved

kubelets `kube-reserved` value can be configured as a static value (via `--kube-reserved=`) or monitored dynamically via cgroup (`--kube-reserved-cgroup=`).
This is for any kubernetes services running outside of kubernetes, usually `kubelet` and a container runtime.

#### Capacity and Availability on a Node

Capacity is stored in the Node object.

```
$ kubectl get node node01 -o json | jq '.status.capacity'
{
  "cpu": "2",
  "ephemeral-storage": "61252420Ki",
  "hugepages-1Gi": "0",
  "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
  "memory": "4042284Ki",
  "pods": "110"
}
```

The allocatable value can be found on the Node, you can note than existing usage doesn't change this value. Only schduleding pods with resource requests will take away from the `allocatable` value.

```
$ kubectl get node node01 -o json | jq '.status.allocatable'
{
  "cpu": "2",
  "ephemeral-storage": "56450230179",
  "hugepages-1Gi": "0",
  "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
  "memory": "3939884Ki",
  "pods": "110"
}
```

### Memory Usage and Pressure

A kube node can also have a "memory pressure" event. This check is done outside of the *allocatable* resource checks above and is more a system level catch all. Memory pressure looks at the current root cgroup memory usage minus the inactive file cache/buffers, similar to the calculation `free` does to remove the file cache.

A node under memory pressure will not have pods scheduled, and will actively try and evict existing pods until the memory pressure state is resolved.

You can set the eviction threshold amount of memory kubelet will maintain available via the `--eviction-hard=[memory.available<500Mi]` flag. The memory requests and usage for pods can help informs the eviction process.

`kubectl top node` will give you the existing memory stats for each node (if you have a metrics service running).

```
$ kubectl top node
NAME                 CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
node01               141m         7%     865Mi           22%
```

If you were not using `cgroups-per-qos` and a number of pods without resource limits, or a number of system daemons then the cluster is likely to have some problems scheduling on a memory constrained system as *allocatable* will be high but the actual value might be really low.

#### Memory Pressure calculation

Kubernetes [Out Of Resource Handling docco](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/) includes a [script](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/memory-available.sh) which emulates kubelets memory monitoring process:

```
# This script reproduces what the kubelet does
# to calculate memory.available relative to root cgroup.

# current memory usage
memory_capacity_in_kb=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}')
memory_capacity_in_bytes=$((memory_capacity_in_kb * 1024))
memory_usage_in_bytes=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes)
memory_total_inactive_file=$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat | grep total_inactive_file | awk '{print $2}')

memory_working_set=${memory_usage_in_bytes}
if [ "$memory_working_set" -lt "$memory_total_inactive_file" ];
then
    memory_working_set=0
else
    memory_working_set=$((memory_usage_in_bytes - memory_total_inactive_file))
fi

memory_available_in_bytes=$((memory_capacity_in_bytes - memory_working_set))
memory_available_in_kb=$((memory_available_in_bytes / 1024))
memory_available_in_mb=$((memory_available_in_kb / 1024))

echo "memory.capacity_in_bytes $memory_capacity_in_bytes"
echo "memory.usage_in_bytes $memory_usage_in_bytes"
echo "memory.total_inactive_file $memory_total_inactive_file"
echo "memory.working_set $memory_working_set"
echo "memory.available_in_bytes $memory_available_in_bytes"
echo "memory.available_in_kb $memory_available_in_kb"
echo "memory.available_in_mb $memory_available_in_mb"
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Allocatable" contains "scheduled-pods"? I don't see it in the docs
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable

Comment: @AntonSmolkov yeah should be `memory.available` derived from `Allocatable` I will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely **YES**, Kubernetes consider memory usage during pod scheduling process.

The scheduler ensures that, for each resource type, the sum of the resource requests of the scheduled containers is less than the capacity of the node. Note that although actual memory or CPU resource usage on nodes is very low, the scheduler still refuses to place a Pod on a node if the capacity check fails. This protects against a resource shortage on a node when resource usage later increases, for example, during a daily peak in request rate.

There are two key concepts in scheduling. First one, the scheduler attempts to filter the nodes that are capable of running a given pod based on resource requests and other scheduling requirements. Second, the scheduler weighs the eligible nodes based on absolute and relative resource utilization of the nodes and other factors. The highest weighted eligible node is selected for scheduling of the pod.
Good explanation of  scheduling in Kuberneres you can find here:  [`kubernetes-scheduling`](https://medium.com/@dominik.tornow/the-kubernetes-scheduler-cd429abac02f).

**Simple example**: your pod normally uses 100 Mi of ram but you run it with a 50 Mi request. If you have a node with 75 Mi free the scheduler may choose to run the pod there. When pod memory consumption later expands to 100 Mi this **puts the node under pressure**, at which point the kernel **may** choose to kill your process. So it is important to get both memory requests and memory limits right. About memory usage, requests and limits you can read more here: [`memory-resource`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/).

A container can exceed its memory request if the **node** has memory available. But a container is not allowed to use more than its memory limit. If a container allocates more memory than its limit, the container becomes a candidate for termination. If the container continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the container is terminated. If a terminated container can be restarted the kubelet restarts it, as with any other type of runtime failure.

I hope its helps.

Comment: Just a note for the example, kubelet initiates it's own node memory pressure state and pod eviction before (hopefully) the kernel OOM killer. kubelet has a default setting of keeping 100MiB memory headroom or it's starts evicting pods. The kernel OOM killer would kick in if kubelet is unable to free up the headroom, or if kubelet had it's cgroups for tracking memory for kubelet and system processes misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kubernetes will consider current memory usage when scheduling Pods (not just `requests`), so your new Pod wouldn't get scheduled on the full node. Of course, there are also a number of [other factors](https://github.com/eBay/Kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/scheduler_algorithm.md).

(FWIW, when it comes to `resources`, a `request` helps the scheduler by declaring a baseline value, and a `limit` kills the Pod when resources exceed that value, which helps with capacity planning/estimation.