# Programmatically find overcommitted Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to be able to programmatically query Kubernetes to find overcommitted nodes.

If I do `kubectl describe nodes`, I get human-readable output including information about resource usage that I'm after, e.g.

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests              Limits
  --------                   --------              ------
  cpu                        786m (40%)            5078m (263%)
  memory                     8237973504500m (74%)  13742432Ki (126%)
```

However, `kubectl describe` doesn't support JSON or YAML output, and `kubectl get nodes -ojson` doesn't include the allocated resource stats. Is there any other way to access this information?

Comment: This is a duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464518/how-to-format-the-output-of-kubectl-describe-to-json

Comment: @dzof31 No, it is not a duplicate. This question concerns programatically finding overcommitted Kubernetes nodes, and there may be other approaches than through `kubectl describe`. Indeed, you'll notice that the accepted answer to the question you linked would not solve this problem.

Comment: @dzof31 except there is a specific API answer for getting the resources values for `describe nodes`

Answer (score 3):

If you run any `kubectl` command with the `--v=6` option the output will include the kubernetes API calls that make up the output.

In the case of `kubectl describe nodes NODE` you will see there is a `api/v1/pods` request that filters pods on the node and removes some "not running" statuses

```
I0828 13:44:29.310208   55233 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Ddocker-desktop%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded 200 OK in 4 milliseconds
```

If you complete this request with authentication information from your `~/.kube/config` file you should be able to get the output.  In this case, using `jq` to filter the output down to the `resources` component of the container spec with CA/Cert/Key auth (base64 decoded).

```
curl --cacert ~/.kube/docker-desktop.ca \
 --cert ~/.kube/docker-desktop.cert \
 --key ~/.kube/docker-desktop.key \
 https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Ddocker-desktop%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded \
| jq '.items[].spec.containers[].resources'
```

```
{}
{}
{
  "limits": {
    "memory": "170Mi"
  },
  "requests": {
    "cpu": "100m",
    "memory": "70Mi"
  }
}
{
  "limits": {
    "memory": "170Mi"
  },
  "requests": {
    "cpu": "100m",
    "memory": "70Mi"
  }
}
{}
{
  "requests": {
    "cpu": "250m"
  }
}
{
  "requests": {
    "cpu": "200m"
  }
}
{}
{
  "requests": {
    "cpu": "100m"
  }
}
{}
{}
```

Running these calls and filters will generally be easier with one of the [kubernetes API clients](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) if you are regularly going to this level.

Comment: I should also note that `kubectl top` will give you instantaneous values for memory from nodes, if you have heapster or metrics-server installed and kubelet is setup correctly to use cgroups. This is collected from the current cgroups on the node so is the more the "actual usage" value for a node than what a node is committed to.

Comment: I have an [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799354/1318694) that details the difference between the two types of memory tracking

Answer (score 0):

You can write the output to a file maybe?

```
kubectl describe > output.txt
```

Comment: The output of `kubectl describe` is not suited for machine processing (not to say it cannot be done, but it would be hacky and brittle, and it would not be a good engineering choice unless there were no other option.)