# How to set node allocatable computation on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm reading the [Reserve Compute Resources for System Daemons](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/) task in Kubernetes docs and it briefly explains how to allocate a compute resource to a node using `kubelet` command and flags `--kube-reserved`, `--system-reserved` and `--eviction-hard`.

I'm learning on [Minikube for masOS](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/macos/) and as far as I got, minikube is configured to use command `kubectl` along with `minikube` command.

For local learning purposes on minikube I don't need to have it set (*maybe it can't be done on minikube)* but

**How this could be done let's say in K8's development environment on a node?**

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457741/11102471

Answer (score 2):

This could be be done by:

**1**. Passing `config` file during cluster initialization or initilize `kubelet` with additional parameters via [config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/),

For cluster initialization using config file [it should contains at least](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1#hdr-Basics):

```
kind: InitConfiguration
kind: ClusterConfiguration
   additional configuratuion types like:
kind: KubeletConfiguration
```

In order to get basic config file you can use `kubeadm config print init-defaults`

**2**. For the live cluster please consider reconfigure current cluster using steps "**Generate the configuration file**" and "**Push the configuration file to the control plane**" like described in ["Reconfigure a Node's Kubelet in a Live Cluster"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/)

**3**. I didn't test it but for `minikube` - please take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#configuring-kubernetes):

Note:

> Minikube has a “configurator” feature that allows users to configure the Kubernetes components with arbitrary values. To use this feature, you can use the --extra-config flag on the minikube start command.
>
> This flag is repeated, so you can pass it several times with several different values to set multiple options.
>
> This flag takes a string of the form component.key=value, where component is one of the strings from the below list, key is a value on the configuration struct and value is the value to set.
>
> Valid keys can be found by examining the documentation for the Kubernetes componentconfigs for each component. Here is the documentation for each supported configuration:
>
> ```
> kubelet
> apiserver
> proxy
> controller-manager
> etcd
> scheduler
> ```

Hope this helped:

Additional community resources:

[Memory usage in kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486023/does-kubernetes-consider-the-current-memory-usage-when-scheduling-pods/56799354#56799354)

Comment: I'll try to go through every step once I get back to this.  [This article also helped me](https://prabhatsharma.in/blog/reserving-compute-resources-for-system-daemons-in-kubernetes-using-node-allocatable/) to understand it a bit more with an implementation example. But there is another problem: how much of resources to allocate to system deamons? I think that should depend on how many processes are running in Kubernetes.

Comment: It can impact [pod eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#best-practices). [General Guidelines](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#general-guidelines) [cluster architecture](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture)